# Find the efficiency class

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, loops

I have to find the efficiency class of this algorithm

```
b = 3
a = 4
for i = 4 to n^2
    if (i mod 2 == 0)
        a = a+2 
    else
        b = b*3
end for
```

I solve it like this, first I find the time for executed a then b and the total is the addition, is it right? I'm not sure if I have to do it like this or not, I let $n=\frac{n^2}{2}$ because of the $\bmod 2$ is it right?

$t_a(n)=\sum_{j=1}^{n^{2}/2}1=\dfrac{n^{2}}{2}$

$t_b(n)=\sum_{j=4}^{n^{2}}1-\dfrac{n^{2}}{2}=n^{2}-\dfrac{n^{2}}{3}-3$

$t(n)=\dfrac{n^{2}}{2}+n^{2}-\dfrac{n^{2}}{3}-3=\Theta (n^{2})$ by the polynomial theorem.

Comment: 0) Your basic approach looks good. 1) Check the limits of your sums, though. Since there are as many odd as even numbers, $t_a$ and $t_b$ should be very similar! 2) You didn't count everything: evaluating the `if` and `for` statements as well as the initialisation have costs, too. Even if you're only counting arithmetic operations, not that maintaining `i` takes such operations!

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: Yes! for the limits I saw it similar to odd and even number but didn't know how to write it as n, for even the 2k you mean I can write it as 2n^2 ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final result is true. But, you have a fault in your computation, as in each iteration you have at least a comparison. Hence, instead of $\frac{n^2}{2}$, we will have $n^2 - 3$. Anyhow, the final result is the time complexity is $\Theta(n^2)$.

Comment: "we will have $n^2$" -- not so. The loop doesn't start with`i=1`.

Comment: you mean I must start solving it from $=\sum_{i=4,6,8,..n^{2}}^{n^{2}}1$ ? then I give j=1 so I can start from 1 ? just like what I do before ?

Comment: @NANA Nope. I mean $t_a(n)=\sum_{j=4}^{n^{2}}1= n^{2} - 3$.

Comment: @NANA  I'd say that's a better starting place, yes, as it follows a general rule. Manipulate the sum until you can simplify it

Comment: why only $n^{2}-3$?  I have to subtract the time of $a$ also right that's why it is  $n^{2}-3-n^{2}/2$ @OmG

Comment: @NANA  i mean $t(n) = \sum_{j=4}^{n^2} 1$ not $t_a$.